# Elasticsearch MongoDb river reference handling

Tags: mongodb, search, elasticsearch, relation

I followed this mongodb example: http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Also I installed a mongodb river in my elasticsearch: https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb

Everything works fine, a user entity has several post entities in mongodb. As i look into elasticsearch there is the following data structure:

```
{
    "_index": "doctrine",
    "_type": "user",
    "_id": "53d7f246e2afecdc03d63af3",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "_id": "53d7f246e2afecdc03d63af3",
       "email": "email@example.com",
       "name": "Bulat S.",
       "posts": [
          "{ \"$ref\" : \"BlogPost\", \"$id\" : \"53d7f246e2afecdc03d63af1\" }",
          "{ \"$ref\" : \"BlogPost\", \"$id\" : \"53d7f246e2afecdc03d63af2\" }"
       ]
    }
 }
```

This also looks really good. But I was wondering about the reference to the posts. The simplest thing I can imagine is just a simple array of post ids like `"posts": ["53d7f246e2afecdc03d63af1", "53d7f246e2afecdc03d63af2"]`. This would made a search very easy. But how can I handle the provided markup by the river? Is there a good query to search in the `posts` field? Why are the `"` escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quotes are escaped because they're inside another set of double quotes. If they weren't escaped it would prematurely signal the end of the string.

The reason you are seeing `DBRef`s stored inside the `posts` field is because Doctrine uses them to map relationships. Checkout [Doctrine - Simple References](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/reference-mapping.html#simple-references) for solely storing the `ObjectId`.

Comment: But the simple references only work with relations to the same type of document, right? Does doctrine still work with user/blogpost relations and simple references?

Comment: The `$ref` field of a `DBRef` contains the collection name for use cases where you are referencing documents that could be stored in a number of different collections. Simple references will only work with "references to documents of a single collection". Since you are solely referencing the `BlogPost` collection in the `post` field you can use simple references. Does that make sense?